# Clean Subversion Repository by Performing an Update

Tags: svn, repository

We would like to modify an existing SVN repository such that the <strike>repository</strike> working copy is cleaned on a customer computer when he performs an update.
The cooperation has been canceled and we want to remove the files from the computer. Of course if the customer has an backup, the files can be restored.

Is this somehow possible? I know I can remove the files from the SVN repo and commit it. But the other revisions can be restored very easily.
Can I create a SVN repo which has the same identifiers as an existing repo but is empty?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you confusing "working copy" & "repository" terms?

Comment: yes, right; I replaced one repository with working copy

Answer (score 0):

You'd better focus on denying the access to your repositories instead of planning to force remove the data on your customer's machines. Most likely, he has a backup after all.

> Is this somehow possible?

Yes, but its absolutely useless in practice in case you want to force the remove operation to your customer's working copies so that he loses all the data.

You can remove the data in the new commit in the repository and as soon as the customer / user runs `svn update` his working copy will become empty. At the same time, he can view the project's history on the server and he can update the working copy to any older revision. Moreover, he can `svnrdump dump` all the projects data with changes history to his computer to recreate the project's repository.